# Ingress return 404 for all services in azure kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Im having an issue after setting up the ingress controller Nginx and ingress resource to manages routes to my services, i keep getting 404 for all services while their end-point is correct.
this is hosted in azure.

Ingress controller is namesapce: ingress-basic
services are namespace: default
ingress resource is in namespace: default

deployment of my services are handled by Helm and Helm File, this a short snip about an endpoint of a service : development-manager-demo

```
Name:              development-manager-demo
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: development-manager-demo
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:          app=development-manager-demo
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.0.22.107
IPs:               <none>
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.192:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

my ingress file looks like this which direct me to two services:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: navigation-service
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
 #tls:
 #- secretName: tls-secret
 #backend:
    #serviceName: defualt-http-backend
    #servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: myservice.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /demo
        backend:
          serviceName: development-manager-demo
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /dev
        backend:
          serviceName: development-manager
          servicePort: 80
```

my ingress:

```
app-ingress     myservice.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com   X.X.X.57   80        20h
```

description of the ingress:

```
Name:             app-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          X.X.X.57
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                                           Path  Backends
  ----                                           ----  --------
  myservice.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
                                                 /demo    development-manager-demo:80 (10.244.0.192:80)
                                                 /dev     development-manager:80 (10.244.0.193:80)
Annotations:                                     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                 From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    45m (x12 over 20h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    15m (x16 over 20h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    15m (x16 over 20h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    15m (x16 over 20h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

When i try to navigate to **myservice.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/demo** or **/dev** i keep getting 404.
can someone help? :)

**EDITED**

I deployed a service in Azure (Angular APP) and configured ingress to route traffic to the app and works perfectly. I believe the problem is more associated with asp.net core Swagger API somehow it not configured right to handle incoming request from an ingress.

my start up class,

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<KafkaOptions>(configuration.GetSection(KafkaOptions.Kafka));
            services.Configure<RestOptions>(configuration.GetSection(RestOptions.Rest));
            services.AddSingleton<IDmsJsonMessageConsumer, DmsJsonMessageConsumer>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDmsJsonMessageProducer, DmsJsonMessageProducer>();
            services.AddSingleton<IVaultManagerService, VaultManagerService>();

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddHttpClient<IVaultManagerHttpService, VaultManagerHttpService>();

            services.AddHealthChecks();

            services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var healthCheckOptions = new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                ResponseWriter = WriteReadinessResponse
            };

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
          
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/readiness", healthCheckOptions);
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/liveness", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    Predicate = (_) => false
                });
            });

            // enable swagger support
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
           {
               c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Demo API V1");
           });
        }
```

can some help me with this? any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It looks like that your `Pod` is receiving a request with `/demo` or `/dev` in path. Are your applications configured to listen on them (`/demo/`, `/dev`) or plain `/`? If they are configured on `/` you will need to use `rewrite-target` annotation to rewrite the request to not include those paths. Could you please check that?

Comment: the service behind **development-manager-demo** is a swagger ASP.net core API, once you lunch it the url generate in the browser is _http://ip/swagger/index.html_, I feel like there is something missing to be configured in the asp.net core setting? I tried you suggested to add **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /** didnt work same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue, in the **launchSettings.json** the configured path is swagger

```
..
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
..
```

by changing the ingress route to swagger it works.

```
..
 paths:
      - path: /swagger
        backend:
          serviceName: development-manager
          servicePort: 80
..
```